# Merging two Binary Search Trees efficiently and create one BST

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

Say I have to create one BST by merging two BSTs where T1 and T2 are both BSTs such that T1 has more nodes than T2 and with this algorithm that, for each node in T2, remove node from T2 and insert the value of node into T1 and finally return T1. Reading other posts the runtime of this algo seems to be O(m * log(n)) where n is number of nodes in T1 and m is number of nodes in T2. I am not 100% sure why this results in that running time complexity though. Could anyone explain to me why it's O(m * log(n))? My first guess was O(m*n) because within the iteration, we have to remove one node from T2 which results in the runtime of O(m) and the following insertion's runtime is O(n) so shouldn't it be O(m*n)?

Comment: insert time complexity is `O(logn)`

Comment: @F.Ju Even if it is not balanced?

Comment: Crucial question, if inconsequential for runtime order of growth: why remove the nodes from T2 one by one? Can't they be processed in an in-order traversal, postponing clean-up?

Answer (score 0):

You said Binary Search Tree, **not** Balanced Binary Search Tree. And, time complexity of Inserting a value into a BST *(Binary Search Tree)*  is:

- Best Case: `O(log(n))`.  (when it is fully balanced).
- Worst Case: `O(n)`.

Since, we are moving all the elements from `T2` *(initially having m elements)*  to `T1` *(initially having n elements)*. Therefore the overall time complexity would be:

- Best Case: `O(m.log(n))`.
- Worst Case: `O(m.n)`.

Whereas, in practical we can consider the average time complexity, which would be in between the Best and Worst Case Scenarios.

**EDIT:** Consider a case for the clarification.

```
T2            T1     # initial BST
#             #
8             3
 \             \
  9             4
   \             \ 
    10            5
     \             \
      11            6
                     \ 
                      7                       
m = 4      &   n = 5      (initial values).

Moving the 8 to the T1 from T2  
T2            T1    
#             #
9             3
 \             \
  10            4
   \             \ 
    11            5
                   \
                    6
                     \ 
                      7
                       \
                        8

Steps taken to insert 8 into its right place = 5 or (n)
Total Steps taken   = 5 or (n)

Moving the 9 to the T1 from T2  
T2            T1    
#             #
10            3
 \             \
  11            4
                 \ 
                  5
                   \
                    6
                     \ 
                      7
                       \
                        8
                         \
                          9

Steps taken to insert 9 into its right place = 6 or (n+1)
Total Steps taken   = 5+6  or (n) + (n+1)

Moving the 10 to the T1 from T2 
T2            T1    
#             #
11            3
               \
                4
                 \ 
                  5
                   \
                    6
                     \ 
                      7
                       \
                        8
                         \
                          9
                           \
                           10

Steps taken to insert 10 into its right place = 7 (n+2)
Total Steps taken   = 5+6+7 or (n) + (n+1) + (n+2) 

Moving the 11 to the T1 from T2 
T2            T1    
#             #
NULL          3
               \
                4
                 \ 
                  5
                   \
                    6
                     \ 
                      7
                       \
                        8
                         \
                          9
                           \
                           10
                             \
                             11

Steps taken to insert 11 into its right place = 8 (n+3)
Total Steps taken   = 5+6+7+8 or (n) + (n+1) + (n+2) + (n+3)
```

Therefore, by observation we can say, in worst case the number of steps to be taken to move `m` number of values from T2 to T1:

```
=> (n) + (n+1) + (n+2) + .......   + (n + (m-1))
=> (n+n+n+...m times) + (1+2+3+....+(m-1))
=> (n.m) + (m.(m-1))/2
```

Since, the `n > m`. therefore, we can neglect the second equation after the addition sign.

Hence, the time complexity: `O(n.m)`.

Comment: What if trees don't have to be balanced at all? would that be O(m*n) still?